# Asynchronous Nodejs communication with GRPC protocol

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, grpc

I'm trying to build a nodejs/express project that communicate between server/client with grpc protocol, in order to make simple Users CRUD action and display datas on the front-end.
Currently, the server side works fine with mysql librairy and a MariaDB database.

As far as I can see within the console, the server side send the datas as expected, but I can't manage to retrieve them on the client side.

Here is the revelent code :

In the server.js file, server side :

```
server.addService(customersProto.CustomerService.service, {
getAll: async(_, callback) => {
    const allUsers = await sql.getAll(db);
    callback(null, { allUsers });
    console.log(allUsers);
},
}
```

The ouput of the console.log :

```
[{"id":"a68b823c-7ca6-44bc-b721-fb4d5312cafc","name":"David","age":33,"adress":"227th Baker Street"},{"id":"a68b823c-7ca6-44bc-b721-fb4d5312cahg","name":"Peter","age":99,"adress":"38th King Street"}
```

In the index.js file, client side :

```
async function getAll() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.getAll(null, (err, data) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("fonction getAll : " + JSON.stringify(data));
            resolve(JSON.stringify(data));
        } else {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
});
}



app.get("/", async(req, res) => {
  const data = await getAll();
  console.log(data);
  res.render("customers", {
    results: JSON.stringify(data),
});
});
```

The output of the console.log :

```
fonction getAll : {"customers":[]}
{"customers":[]}
```

I don't understand why the array is empty...

Have you got an idea to retrieve my datas ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've found my problem.

Because the Proto Buffer needs an array of "customers", I didn't realise that I couldn't give any name to the variable in the callback of the getAll function (server side).

That solve the problem : In the server.js file, server side :

```
server.addService(customersProto.CustomerService.service, {
getAll: async(_, callback) => {
    const customers = await sql.getAll(db);        
    callback(null, { customers });        
    );       
},
}
```